# Custom Tabular Suggestion for Sap.m.Input

Tags: sapui5

I want to create a custom Suggestion for a input field in SAPUI5. I managed to create a tabular suggestion which include 3 columns {`Name`, `AdName`, `Telno`}.
This is my code:

```
<Input id="_txtCustomerName" liveChange="liveChange" placeholder="{i18n>customername}" showTableSuggestionValueHelp="false" 
        suggestionItemSelected="suggestionSelected" startSuggestion="1" showSuggestion="true" suggest="suggest" suggestionRows="{/results}" >
            <suggestionColumns>
                <Column hAlign="Begin" popinDisplay="Inline" demandPopin="true">
                    <Label text="{i18n>customername}"/>
                </Column>
                <Column hAlign="Center" popinDisplay="Inline" demandPopin="true" minScreenWidth="Tablet">
                    <Label text="{i18n>address}"/>
                </Column>
                <Column hAlign="End" popinDisplay="Inline" demandPopin="true">
                    <Label text=" {i18n>phoneno}"/>
                </Column>
            </suggestionColumns>
            <suggestionRows>
                <ColumnListItem>
                <cells>
                    <Label text="{Name}"/>
                    <Label text="{AdName}, {City}"/>
                    <Label text="{Telno}"/>
                </cells>
                </ColumnListItem>
            </suggestionRows>
        </Input>
```

It loaded the data from ABAP server to the SuggestionRows property properly, the only filtered by `Name`. Now I want to filter the suggestionTable by `Name` and `Telno` as well. Any suggestion ?
P/s: I tried to follow a guide from this thread: https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3811696 but it seems not working for me.

```
    suggest: function(oEvent) {
                var sValue = oEvent.getParameter("suggestValue");
                var filters = new sap.ui.model.Filter([
                    new sap.ui.model.Filter("Name",
                        sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains,
                        sValue),
                    new sap.ui.model.Filter("Telno",
                        sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains,
                        sValue)
                ], false);
                oEvent.getSource().getBinding("suggestionRows").filter(
                    [filters]);
}
```

it returns undefind for `oEvent.getSource().getBinding("suggestionRows")`, means I can't find the `suggestionRows` aggregation.

Comment: Can you also add the XML View specific code for your problem ?

Comment: yeah I update my post. Thank you a lot.

Comment: The code you have provided does not seem to have any problem, this may be due to some other dependent code

Comment: Sorry for taking long time to reply! My code sure is working. But I want the suggestion filter by Name and Telno. Now using this code I can only take suggestion by only property `Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **sap.m.Input** control will filter the data by "Name" even if you add your own filter. You will have to disable the default filters & add your own filter logic. You can disable it by changing the filterSuggests property to false.

```
<Input id="_txtCustomerName" filterSuggests="false" ....
```

This will disable the default filtering logic used by the control as mentioned [here](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Input.html#setFilterSuggests). Now your custom filter logic should work.

Comment: MayI ask, if I've already filtered the data at server side, and set all the expected suggest data to the model. Will it show all the data of the suggestionTable without filtering anything if I set this property 'false'?

Comment: My problem is I can't get the `suggestionRows` aggregation from the oEvent.getSource() nor oEvent.getParameters(). I tried to find it : `console.log(oEvent.getSource());` but still can't find it. Please help~!

Comment: What UI5 version do you use ? Also ensure that the suggest method is exclusive to your Input control & not triggered by anything else.

Comment: 1.30 sir. I tried but can't find it anywhere. But your answer are helpful in my case. I managed to disable the default filter mechanism. Now I can do the filtering myself not using ui5 anymore but in code ABAP to filter on the server side. Thank you very much.